# Not able to boot into Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10. My system boots directly into Windows and does not show a GRUB menu, so I am unable to access Ubuntu, however it is installed.
Basically I've tried every single possible solution what I found on the interet with no success.
My last attempt to fix the issue was to run a boot-repair from a live USB. The result is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4PjsFCM96B/
My system still boots directly into Windows and I am not able to change the boot order, since Ubuntu is not listed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Although the answer you got so far touches in an important consideration when dual-booting - disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a MUST - that won't be enough. Your report clearly shows Windows with boot priority. You need to open UEFI settings > Boot and select "Ubuntu"instead.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some like Acer require you to set "trust" from within UEFI on the Ubuntu/shimx64.efi boot file. Others like HP, do not seem to support the standard efibootmgr change of boot order. They do work from within UEFI settings (not UEFI's boot menu) to change boot order.  Many also require UEFI update and SSD firmware updates.

Answer (score 2):

You haven’t said what you’ve tried, but I suspect Windows has fast startup enabled - you need to disable that to get grub to load:

In the Windows search bar, enter ‘power and sleep settings’, open it, then select ‘additional power settings’, then ‘choose what the power button does’. You’ll probably have to click ‘change settings that are correctly unavailable’ to deselect ‘turn on fast startup’.

Thanks to ChanganAuto: you’ll also need to open UEFI settings > Boot and change to "Ubuntu"instead.

When you’ve done that, reboot and hopefully grub menu will appear. I hope that helps.